# Where to output the colder air from a "heat-pump boiler"?

Tags: heating-systems

In an average family house, where should we let the colder air from a "heat-pump boiler" out?

1) - to the inside of the family house (ex.: heated in winter, so letting cold air in it..)

2) - to the outside of the family house?

Answer (score 2):

At least in the UK, domestic air source heat pumps are normally used to take heat from outside the house (cooling the air outside) and use it to heat water and/or the air inside the house. So the cooled air would go outside the house.

If you use a heat pump the other way round to take heat from inside the house and put it outside then we call it air conditioning. I have heard of reversible heat pumps that cool in the summer (heat inside to outside) and heat  in the winter (heat outside to inside), but it always goes one way or the other and never heats and cools inside the building at the same time.

Comment: The only exception to @kagekiba's answer is the newest heat pumps, which use the rejected heat generated while running as an air conditioner in the summer to heat hot water for use inside the house at the same time the house is being cooled.